# PhoneGap Is there anyway caching logged user

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Is there anyway cache login credentials for automatic login functionality.
In addition , i used html5 and jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, We use localStorage in html5 to save the access credendtials for our webapps/phonegap. At page startup we check if we are logged in, if not send the access credentials to server in background and become logged in. All this is only if user enables 'remember me'.

We are using pure javascript, so other options might exist within jquery as well as elsewhere.

Side note, this should be seen as a low security option depending on how/what you save to the phone, anyone who can physically get hold of the phone could extract the credentials.

Comment: Thanks @rlb. Localstorage solved my issue; localStorage.setItem("name", "xxx")  localStorage.getItem("name")